# Existe desvanatgens de criar um componente no React por função ao invés de Classe?

Tags: funções, react, classes

Existe uma desvantagem em criar os componentes no `React` por função ao invés de classe?

No caso de Classe, o componente não precisa ter ID para ser acessado internamente e alterar suas propriedades porque ele altera estado. Já na função não tem estado, então só achei a solução de mandar por fora para o HTML provocar o render do browser.

Existe uma maneira interna de alterar uma propriedade do componente por função?

Tipo:

```
function Counter (props){
    const style = {
         color: props.color
    }       
    const id = props.id;
    var numero = props.numero;
    return (
         <div>
            <button onClick={
                    function(){
                        numero = numero + 1;
                        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "A conta está em: " + numero;
             }
            }>+</button>
            <span id={props.id} style={style}>A conta está em: {numero}</span>
        </div>
       );
    }
```

Comment: Não existe desvantagem é somente o novo jeito (API) que foi criado. Agora o seu código acima tem problemas conceituais para quem deseja fazer isso em `REACT`! Tipo não é assim `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` que faz ...

Comment: Segundo o próprio site oficial do React, para eles, há vantagens em se usar funções e desvantagens em se usar classes. Se os próprios criadores dizem isso, quem sou eu para dizer o contrário? https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Porque fez assim: `numero = numero + 1;
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "A conta está em: " + numero;`?

Comment: Na verdade foi só um teste porque estou vendo um curso e o cara ensina por Classe e eu tentei fazer a mesma coisa por função. Mas não achei outra maneira de alterar o valor do contador internamente, pois a props.numero é "read only". Qual seria a forma correta?

Comment: Entendi, então em torno desse componente Counter tem um componente Pai ???

Comment: Na verdade só uma div porque o React não permite que tenha mais de 1 componente pai. Então se precisar ter vários componentes, como botões etc, precisam todos serem filhos de 1 pai.

Comment: No caso de Classe, o componente não precisa ter ID para ser acessado internamente e alterar suas propriedades porque ele altera estado. Já na função não tem estado, então só achei a solução de mandar por fora para o HTML provocar o render do browser

Comment: Amigo coloque tudo na pergunta só esse pedaço fica complicado

Comment: `Já na função não tem estado` tem sim! tem o hook para fazer isso ...

Comment: Obrigado, você tem um endereço de artigo que explica bem sobre os Hooks? Vou estudar mais a fundo.

Comment: Olha a sua afirmação que é um erro (https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) leia aqui

Answer (score 0):

Anterior a introdução dos hooks, a maior diferença entre um componente que extende React.Component (classe) e um stateless component (função) era a possibilidade de manter um estado interno apenas no primeiro. Após a adição dos hooks, temos a possibilidade de utilizar estado em ambos.

Caso queira transformar seu stateless numa classe voce deve:

1. Criar uma classe ES6, com o mesmo nome, estendendo React.component.
2. Adicionar um único método vazio chamado render().
3. Mova o corpo da função para o método render().
4. Substitua props por this.props no corpo de render().
5. Exclua a declaração da função vazia restante.

Para utilizar um estado local a uma Classe

1. Substitua this.props.numero por this.state.numero no método render()
2. Adicione um construtor na classe que atribui o numero inicial no this.state
3. Modifique o onClick do seu botão para atualizar o estado com this.setState({ numero: novoValor })

Vale a pena você dá uma olhada [nesse trecho da documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) do react principalmente no tópico **State e Ciclo de Vida** que foi de onde veio essa resposta.

Sobre o uso de **hooks**, voce consegue encontrar mais detalhes [nessa página da documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).